# C++ editing the elements of char* argv[]

Tags: c++, c, linux

All of you know this function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

}
```

I want to write a command line interface in Linux for my program, which is usually done by `getopt_long()`

My program would be executed from command line like this:

```
pop3 get --limit 25 --recent
```

Hence, the `argv[]` would include `pop3` as its program name, and the rest are treated as options.
I want to delete `pop3` from my string and set the first token after it as the first element of the array. Is there a way to do that other than looping through?

Comment: Easy solution: slice it off: `argv++; argc--;`

Comment: Trick: You cannot modify the strings belonging to read only memory, just stop pointing to them.

Comment: *"usually done by `getopt_long()`"*. What did you mean by that. Are you going to use `getopt_long()` or not?

Comment: @user3386109 I am going to use it. What I have done is using a loop and simply creating a new array.

Comment: If you're going to use `getopt_long`, then the correct answer is, "You don't have to do anything, `getopt_long` automatically skips the first argument."

Comment: @user3386109 I know that buddy, I want it to escape the second argument, too.

Comment: Yes, and there is a correct way to do that, buddy. What you want to do is ignore the "get" in the command line, which is easily done, and the answer you accepted is not the right way to do it.

Comment: @Asim, there is no read-only memory involved here. Neither `argc`, `argv` or *the characters pointed by it* are read-only, and this by design, so that the program can erase the data if it wants.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Increment the `argv` pointer, and decrement the `argc`.
Example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    argc--;
    argv++;

    return 0;
}
```

This works, because when you increment `argv`, you still have the previous data in memory, it's just that the base address of the `argv` has increased. And you decrement `argc`, because you now have one less argument.